# Eloquent multiple rows insert and in one array loop

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have user input following the rules below;

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'phone_number' => 'required|array',
            'amount' => 'required|string|max:4',
            'phone_number_debit' => 'required|string|max:15',
        ];
    }
```

I would want to save the data in a model `Transaction`. For the phone_number it is an array that could have one value or multiple. So that leaves for foreach loop.

This is what I want to achieve, save different rows determined by the number of records in the array.

```
$transaction = new Trasaction();
$transaction->phone_number = $req->phone_number; //Value in the array
$transaction->amount = $req->amount;
$transaction->phone_number_debit = $req->phone_number_debit;
$transaction->save();
```

Save diffrent records according to the records in the phone_number array.

However I can not think of a way to achieve this.

Anyone?

Comment: Can you create an entry for each `phone_number` element?

Comment: @IanRodrigues how do I achieve this? The array is in the same request as others.

Comment: Why not create a child table? One Transaction would have many phone numbers. It would make it easier to manage.

Comment: You spelled transaction wrong in your example btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, in a nutshell:

```
collect(request('phone_number'))->each(function ($phone) use ($req) {
    $transaction = new Trasaction();
    $transaction->phone_number = $phone; // element of the array
    $transaction->amount = $req->amount;
    $transaction->phone_number_debit = $req->phone_number_debit;
    $transaction->save();
});
```

*TL;DR*

**One-to-Many Relationship**

In order to get a better code, you can create a `transaction_phones` table, creating a `one-to-many` relationship.

You'll create a `TransactionPhone` model and add this:

```
public function transaction()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Transaction::class);
}
```

The `TransactionPhone` migration:

```
Schema::create('transaction_phones', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('transaction_id');
    $table->string('phone_number');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

In your `Transaction` model you'll have the inverse:

```
public function phones()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TransactionPhone::class);
}

public function addPhone($phone)
{
    return $this->phones()->create(['phone_number' => $phone]);
}
```

And in you Controller:

```
$transaction = Trasaction::create(request()->only('amount', 'phone_number_debit'));

collect(request('phone_number'))->each(function ($phone) use ($transaction) {
    $transaction->addPhone($phone);
});
```

I hope this answer can help you.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
$data = request(['amount', 'phone_number', 'phone_number_debit']);

foreach($data['phone_number'] as $phone_number) {
    Trasaction::create([
       'amount' => $data['amout'],
       'phone_number' => $phone_number,
       'phone_number_debit' => $data['phone_number_debit']
    ]);
}
```

make sure in your `Trasaction` modal you've set to fillable property like this :

```
class Trasaction extends Model 
{
    protected $fillable = ['amount', 'phone_number', 'phone_number_debit'];
}
```